# how to compare 2 string with python

Tags: python, string, compare, character

I want to compare two strings in python.

For example:

```
str1 = 'hello'

str2 = 'lolhe'
```

I want to compare `str1` and `str2` and have the result be `True` because they contain the same characters.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)
```

This sorts the strings first and compares the results.  If they have the same characters, those characters will always be ordered the same way after sorting.

If you don't care about repeated characters (e.g. if `'hello'` should equal `'helo'`) then you can use a set:

```
set(str1) == set(str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = 'hello'
t2 = "lolhe"
hist1 = {}
hist2 = {}
for x in t1: hist1[x] = hist1.setdefault(x,0)+1
for x in t2: hist2[x] = hist2.setdefault(x,0)+1
hist1 == hist2
```

[edit] the sorted method in the other answer is better